# connect UITableView + UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Right now I have an indexed UITableView that goes to a detail view but i want it to go to another UITableView then a detail view.

my code like this:

`
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
displyAnnController *anController = [[displyAnnController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnnView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:anController animated:YES];
        [anController release];
        anController = nil;
        break;
    case 1:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        [dvController release];
        dvController = nil;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}`
```

and when I press the cell with index 0 in the simulator, the program is crash!

what's the problem? pleas help me ..

---

No, I didn't override the `-initWithNibName`, I just use it as the same way here,but to push to ControlView NOT TableView.Also,no errors in debug console.
and I have tried to release the controllers after the switch block, but the program still crash :(
anyway, it's work when I write:

```
displyAnnController *anController = [[displyAnnController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]];
```

instead of :

```
displyAnnController *anController = [[displyAnnController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnnView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
```

Temporarily, I accept this just to complete my work! but I hope to find any help example because no need to be as group.

thanks all for help and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

View the debug console (`Cmd-Shift-R`) and see what the error is.

Are you overriding the `-initWithNibName` message on `displyAnnController`?  Or the `-viewDidLoad` message?

You also have a memory leak.  You always `+alloc` both controllers, but only `-release` one of them.  Don't `+alloc` your controller unless you are going to actually use it.

Comment: Yes release your view controllers after the switch block. & why dont you create your viewcontrollers in -viewDidLoad in this view controller add them in an array & use objectAtIndex:row to push the respective view controller on the navigationstack in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  method.
And as Branon said check your console on what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think your application is crashing because first you have released the view and then you are making it nil.If it is released once then it is not getting the reference to make it nil.Try it once.It may work.